# Alpha 3.9 version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory- No refreshtoken member on AuthenticationResult

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-.net

In the Alpha 3.9 version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory there are no refreshtoken member on AuthenticationResult. How do I get the RefreshToken for the Microsoft Graph API? @vibronet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Starting with ADAL 3.0, refresh tokens are not returned. Please see Vittorio's blog post for more details: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/.

Comment: Will ADAL 3.0 set a default tokencache when you initialize the Authcontext that it ferences by userid then?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes. In fact, I am using ADAL 2.x, and if I don't specify a custom token cache, it uses a default token cache where the key is user id.